RDLC Files Not Automatically Deploying to Azure App Service
I'm experiencing an issue with deploying RDLC files in my project to Azure App Service.
Is there a way to configure the deployment process so that RDLC files are automatically included when deploying to Azure App Service? I would like to avoid the manual upload step if possible.
Here are the details:
Project Setup: My RDLC files are included in the project with the following settings:
Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Copy always
Issue: Despite these settings, when I deploy the project to Azure App Service, the RDLC files are not automatically included. After deployment, I have to manually upload the RDLC files using the advanced tools in Azure.
Steps Taken So Far:
Verified the build action and copy settings for the RDLC files.
Checked the deployment settings to ensure all files are being included.

Can you provide the log stream of your Azure app service?

are you using .net core or .net framework?

Is it 4.7.2 or 4.2.7? please confirm

it is net framework 4.7.2

The issue is with the properties of the RDLC file.
To automatically include RDLC files to azure app service follow the below steps

Change the build action to "Content".
Change the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always".
This will ensure that the RDLC file is included during deployment


You can find the deployed files in Azure under Site/wwwroot in Kudu.


My RDLC file is stored in the Resources folder in my project.


Thanks to @help.boldreports.com for clear explanation, by following this doc I created a sample ASP .NET MVC Application (.Net framework) with a RDLC file in it.
Successfully deployed the app to Azure App Service and rendered the RDLC file.
Local Output:

Output after deployment:


I do not want to manually upload files to Azure under Site/wwwroot in Kudu. I tried using other solutions but they did not work for me.

I didn't add manually, it automatically deployed while deploying the app to azure app service

When I deploy the app to Azure App Service, the RDLC files are not getting uploaded automatically.

once follow the doc which I've provided, and make sure your rdlc file properties are correctly configured.

I followed the instructions in the document you provided, but it didn't work

Have you added license in your global.asax code? and also hope you added correct path of rdlc file in your index.cshtml.

@Omkar follow the doc and make sure you configure everything correctly.

@Omkar Please check if the solution helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

It didn’t work as you suggested, but when I set the build action to 'Additional files,' I was able to upload the RDLC file to the Azure App Service automatically when publishing the code.
